# php SOAP xml Client not working: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get the currency from the National Bank.
The only way they support is with SOAP.

But I can never get it to work...

Firstly I tried this:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://www.nbrm.gov.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx');


$params = array('StartDate' => '10.08.2016', 'EndDate' => '10.08.2016');
$response = $soapclient->GetExchangeRate($params);

var_dump($response);
```

Also tried this:

```
$url = 'http://www.nbrm.gov.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement("<GetExchangeRate></GetExchangeRate>");
$xmlr->addChild('StartDate', '10.08.2016');
$xmlr->addChild('EndDate', '10.08.2016');


$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();

$result = $client->CustomerSearchS($params);
```

---

These would be the operators: http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx?op=GetExchangeRate

```
POST /klservice/kurs.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.nbrm.mk
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/GetExchangeRate"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetExchangeRate xmlns="http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/">
      <StartDate>string</StartDate>
      <EndDate>string</EndDate>
    </GetExchangeRate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However all I get all the time is the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.nbrm.gov.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx' : failed to load external entity "http://www.nbrm.gov.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx" in`

---

I'd like to point out that when viewing my php configuration everything for SOAP to function is enabled.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the endpoint load the WSDL in your browser? It's a 404 for me

Comment: @RobbieAverill apparently its without the .gov part: **http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx** but still get the error  heres a PDF: `http://www.nbrm.mk/WBStorage/Files/_Devizni_Rezervi_UpatstvoWebServiceEN.pdf`

Comment: add `?wsdl` to the end of your initial SOAP URL

Comment: @RobbieAverill That works. However I've got encoding problems now...looks like this: `object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetExchangeRateResult"]=> string(14349) " 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 978 EUR Р•РњРЈ 1 61.4951 EMU РµРІСЂРѕ Euro 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 840 USD РЎ Рђ Р” 1 55.511 USA РЎРђР” РґРѕР»Р°СЂ US dollar 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 826 GBP Р’.Р‘СЂРёС‚Р°РЅРёСР° 1 72.0083 U.K. Р±СЂРёС‚Р°РЅСЃРєР° С„СѓРЅС‚Р° British pound 2016-08-09T00:00:00+02:00 149 2016-08-10T00:00:00+02:00 756 CHF РЁРІР`...